# clEnqueueReadBuffer return a void buffer

Tags: opencl

I am trying to implement an OpenCL project that should take in input two "grey" channels images and return a "grey" channel buffer

My OpenCL code:

```
 __kernel void motion_detection(__global uchar* bgImage, __global uchar* motionImage,__global uchar* outputImage)
{
  int i = get_global_id(0);
  int tsh = 7;
  uchar bgEl = bgImage[i];
  uchar motionEl = motionImage[i];


float bg = convert_float(bgEl);
float mo = convert_float(motionEl);
float temp = fabs(bg-mo);

if(temp>tsh){temp=255.0;
 }else
       {temp=0.0;
     }

outputImage[i] = convert_uchar(bg);
}
```

My Host:

```
// get width and height of input image
height = inputImage->rows;
width = inputImage->cols;

// get the pointer to pixel data
cl_uchar* inputImageData = inputImage->data;
cl_uchar* motionImageData = motionImage->data;
cl_uchar* outputImageData = outputImage->data;
```

After set up buffers:

```
// Create memory object for input Image
inputImageBuffer = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
    width * height * greyPixelSize,
    inputImageData,
    &status);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clCreateBuffer failed. (inputImageBuffer)");

motionImageBuffer = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
    width * height * greyPixelSize,
    motionImageData,
    &status);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clCreateBuffer failed. (inputImageBuffer)");


// Create memory objects for output Image
outputImageBuffer = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
     CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
    width * height * greyPixelSize,
    0,
    &status);
```

Settting up arguments and executing OpenCL kernel:

```
// input buffer image
status = clSetKernelArg(
    kernl,
    0,
    sizeof(cl_mem),
    &inputImageBuffer);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clSetKernelArg failed. (inputImageBuffer)");

status = clSetKernelArg(
    kernl,
    1,
    sizeof(cl_mem),
    &motionImageBuffer);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clSetKernelArg failed. (inputImageBuffer)");

    // outBuffer imager
    status = clSetKernelArg(
    kernl,
    2,
    sizeof(cl_mem),
    &outputImageBuffer);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clSetKernelArg failed. (outputImageBuffer)");

status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
    commandQueue,
    kernl,
    1,
    NULL,
    globalThreads,
    localThreads,
    0,
    NULL,
    &ndrEvt);
clFinish(commandQueue);
```

**Here is my problem, when this intruction is executed it returns outputImageData as "\0" and nothing else:**

```
status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(
    commandQueue,
    outputImageBuffer,
    CL_TRUE,
    0,
    width * height * greyPixelSize,
    outputImageData,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clEnqueueReadBuffer failed.");
```

Comment: You use CL_WRITE_ONLY flag for output buffer. Doesn't that mean the buffer is not accessible on host?

Comment: actually it's CL_MEM_READ_WRITE

Comment: CL_WRITE_ONLY is from the point of view of the _device_ not the _host_, so is fine here. You _want_ 0 back from clEnqueueReadBuffer, that indicates it worked. When it returns your buffer should have been read (since you set the blocking_read flag).

Comment: Does _bgImage_ contain some meaningful content? Your kernel seems to copy bgImage into outputImage as-is, with conversion to float and back to uchar for writing the result. Anyway, if in doubt about clEnqueueReadBuffer, it should be best to simply write constant value from this kernel and see reading the buffer works ok.

Comment: @harism yes it does. I'm subtracting backgroundImages pixels from motionImage if this subtraction is larger than the threshold then set the pixel to 255 on outputimage.

Comment: @Dithermaster I would like to have an array (outputImageData in this case) back full of chars not just one value, that's my problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the output value be convert_uchar(temp) in that case? In any case the original problem was reading the buffer values not evaluate the kernel, any luck with that?

Comment: @harism I've runned my kernel on IntelSDK and the result is fine... even changing the threshold, gives the same result.

Comment: @NicoMkhatvari So output array is filled correctly? As a test, change your kernel to write a known value, like a hardcoded 5. Do you get that back in your output array? If so, the problem lies in your kernel's math. If not, the problem lies in your data transfer. Divide and conquer the problem.

Comment: @NicoMkhatvari: What did you find? Was the problem in the kernel or buffer transfer?

Comment: I have changed if condition  in kernel to (temp <tsh)and it worked. My outputImagedata was full of characters as it was expected to be. But still I cann't give any explanation to this, because it is just simmetric solution to the problem.